# Discuss continuity of $\sin(1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have one question. How to prove $f(x)= \sin(1/x)$ is continuous everywhere if it is given that at $x=0$, $f(x)=0$? Can it be the same explanation like, $\sin(1/x)$ is continuous on all its domain wherever it is defined. As the range of $(1/x)$ is the domain of $\sin(1/x)$, $f(x)$ is continuous at all $x$ except $0$. Now since it is additionally given that $f(x) =0$ at $x=0$, so we can say that $\sin(1/x)$is defined for all real numbers. But how to show that the left hand and right limits are equal to $0$?

Comment: $\sin(1/x)$ is does not go to $0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. Your functions is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove it, because it's not true.

Your function $f$ is continuous away from $0$, but it is not continuous a $0$.  Indeed, for any $\delta>0$ there is some $x\in(0,\delta)$ such that $f(x)=1$.

The function you are describing is a common example of a function that is *not* continuous.  Note that whatever value you make $f$ take at $0$, it will still not be continuous.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking that only. Thanks for clarification.